# What is exec in Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT and why is a process started twice without it?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim

# Copy the files
COPY target/app-1.0.jar /home/app.jar
COPY conf/log4j.xml /home/conf/
COPY conf/bootstrap.properties /home/conf/

WORKDIR /home


ENV APP_OPTS="-Dversion=1 -Dkey=value"

# Default log4j config - logs INFO
ARG LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE=conf/log4j.xml
ENV LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE=$LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE

ENV BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG=conf/bootstrap.properties

ENTRYPOINT java $APP_OPTS -DBOOTSTRAP_CONFIG=$BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG -jar app.jar
```

and I see from `docker top` command:

```
UID   PID   PPID  C  STIME  TIME     CMD
root  7756  7735  0  19:20  00:00:00 /bin/sh -c java $APP_OPTS -DBOOTSTRAP_CONFIG=$BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG -jar app.jar
root  7783  7756  41 19:20  00:00:05 java -Dversion=1 -Dkey=value -DBOOTSTRAP_CONFIG=conf/bootstrap.properties -jar app.jar
```

what when I add `exec` before the ENTRYPOINT, I see only the last process.

`ENTRYPOINT exec java $APP_OPTS -DBOOTSTRAP_CONFIG=$BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG -jar app.jar`

Why is this so and what is the *magic* that exec does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ENTRYPOINT` is run as a shell command, so what you're seeing is PID 7756, which is the shell (you can see that the CMD starts with `/bin/sh`), and PID 7783, which is the actual java process (you can see that the CMD starts with `java`).

[`exec`](https://man.cx/exec(1)), when run by the shell *replaces* the shell process with the child process, so you only see the java process.

This is generally a good idea, because most of the time for a server (or anything running in the background really) you don't need the functionality that running inside a shell gives you (for example job control: Ctrl-Z, `fg`, `bg`, `jobs`...).

Comment: But, the functionality which the shell gives, I suppose that you can get it even with exec if you run in interactive mode with `-it` flag.

Comment: Yes, because in that case you are getting the functionality from the shell that you are calling `docker` from

Comment: Also, why the variables aren't parsed in the first process? We can see the variable names with $ symbol  `/bin/sh -c java $APP_OPTS -DBOOTSTRAP_CONFIG=$BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG -jar app.jar` rather than their values!

Comment: Variable substitution is something that the shell, not docker, does. So the command that is started by docker (`/bin/sh -c ...`) has the variables visible, while the command that `sh` starts has the variables replaced